# Use bash when ksh is shell

Tags: bash, shell, profile

I have access to several RHEL systems that use Active Directory for user accounts and a NFS mount for home directories.

Our login shell is stored in Active Directory and is always `/bin/ksh`.  I want to always have `/bin/bash`, so I figured I could accomplish this in `~/.profile`.  After reading several posts here and on SO I have come up with this:

```
if [ ! -n "$BASH" ] ;then
    SHELL=`type -P bash`
    exec bash -l;
fi
```

- Is this a standard/good way of doing this?
- I read `! -n "$BASH"` as `NOT ("$BASH" is NOT null)`

  - So `true` if it IS null and `false` if NOT null.
  - If so then why not just `-z "$BASH"` or even `! "$BASH"`?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/109625/72456

Comment: @αғsнιη:  Doesn't explain `! -n` or anything else I've asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that you show could very well be used to start a `bash` login shell from your `~/.profile` file.  I personally would use `command` to detect the presence of `bash` like so:

```
if [ -z "$BASH" ]; then
    shell=$( command -v bash )
    if [ -n "$shell" ]; then
        exec env SHELL="$shell" bash --login
    fi
    unset shell
    echo 'Bash not present, continuing...' >&2
fi
```

This gets the path to `bash` into `$shell` which is then used in a test of whether `bash` is available *and* to set the `SHELL` environment variable for `bash`.

Whether to use `[ ! -n "$BASH" ]` or `[ -z "$BASH" ]` is of minor importance (so do whatever feels right and is easiest to read), but I'd probably *not* use `! [ "$BASH" ]` or `[ ! "$BASH" ]`.  In the general case you may end up testing strings that start with dashes, which could confuse the test, so it's better stick to `-n` or `-z` when testing whether strings are empty or not.

You may also want to keep `~/.profile` largely untouched (apart from the above) if the admins of the system one day decides to uninstall `bash`, and instead write a separate `~/.bash_profile` file.  The `bash` shell would use `~/.bash_profile`, if it is available, instead of `~/.profile`, and a failure in launching `bash` would result in your default login shell successfully using `~/.profile` without stumbling over possible bashisms.

Comment: Thanks!  Won't `"$shell" bash -l` eval to `/bin/bash bash -l`?  What is that?

Comment: @AbraCadaver No, `exec env SHELL="$shell" bash -l` would expand to `exec env SHELL="/bin/bash" bash -l` which replaces the current shell with `bash` and sets `SHELL` to `/bin/bash`.  The `env` utility is used to execute another command and setting environment variables for that command.